# Table Cells occupy entire page in HTML

Tags: html, css, node.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to build a table with 6 columns. I haven't added any styles but all the cells occupy 100% width making the table display as a single column[image]

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title 1</th>
      <th>Title 2</th>
      <th>Title 3</th>
      <th>Title 4</th>
      <th>Title 5</th>
      <th>Title 6</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    {{#each projects}}
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Show me your code. Looks like you did not use 'td' and 'tr' properly.

Comment: added the code brother

Comment: Do you have any styling? Any CSS code used? Your html structure is correct.

Comment: i haven't used any css.

Comment: That is so weird. Try inspecting your code in browser using development tool. Or handlebars.js could have default styling.

Comment: try checking your rendered html? probably tr tag hasn't been closed?
this current code is correct

Comment: no issues found in the rendered code

Comment: no issues found, everything seems to be good

Comment: Do you have any included documents to your code? (ex. css files, js files)

Comment: no i don't have any such dicuments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I'm using handlebars as my view engine and handlebars did not include the table styles. It missed the styles for . So adding display: flex made the job